# Can't place my DIV 10px from bottom

Tags: html, css

would you have any idea why my red div (.testbox) is not placed 10px from bottom as I would like it to be and despite the `margin-bottom: 10px`? See http://jsfiddle.net/Hs977/
Thanks for your help

```
body {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.38;
  color: rgb(21, 84, 244);
  margin: 0;
  margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  min-height: 300px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-1020-711-1.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-color: rgb(222, 222, 222);
}

h1 {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 39px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  font-size: 37px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.38;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(0,0,0);
}


.blablatext {
  margin-top: 16px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.38;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(21, 84, 244);
}

.testbox {
float: right;
width: 200px;
height: 90px;
background: red;
margin-right: 20px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: try using absolute positioning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does not work that way.  To place the div at a specified distance from the bottom of it's container, you need to use `position:absolute` on the div and set `position:relative` on the container.  Then use `bottom:10px;` to place it 10px from it's parents bottom.

Updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Hs977/1/

Answer (score 1):

from the [Cascading Style Sheets Level 2 Revision 1 (CSS 2.1) Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#absolute-positioning)

> In the absolute positioning model, a box is explicitly offset with
>   respect to its containing block. It is removed from the normal flow
>   entirely (it has no impact on later siblings). An absolutely
>   positioned box establishes a new containing block for normal flow
>   children and absolutely (but not fixed) positioned descendants.
>   However, the contents of an absolutely positioned element do not flow
>   around any other boxes. They may obscure the contents of another box
>   (or be obscured themselves), depending on the stack levels of the
>   overlapping boxes.

since your header have height defined:

```
  height: 600px;
  min-height: 300px;
```

you can specify `absolute` position, then set bottom position

```
.testbox {
float: right;
width: 200px;
height: 90px;
background: yellow;
margin-right: 20px;
position:absolute;
bottom:0;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/InferOn/Hs977/8/

I don't know why would you define `float` for *.textbox*